# External magnetic field in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, high-performance-computing, condensed-matter, magnetic-field

I have never found any tags or documentation regarding external magnetic field in VASP but in different well known [published articles](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/6/eaaw5685)$^1$, the implementation of the external magnetic field by VASP has been discussed.

Can anyone please explain **how is it possible to simulate the external magnetic field in VASP**?

1. Li, Jiaheng, et al. "Intrinsic magnetic topological insulators in van der Waals layered MnBi2Te4-family materials." Science Advances 5.6 (2019): eaaw5685.

Comment: +1. We also have a VASP chatroom, could you drop by and say hello at least once? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp

Comment: EFIELD has been implemented since at least 4.6.
Now you just have to sort out which direction.

Answer (score 7):

**VASP can't deal with the external magnetic field**, but VASP can deal with the spin-polarized and noncolinear magnetism. You should read carefully the cited paper. As far as I have known, MnBi2Te4 is AFM semiconductor. You can do the spin-polarized calculation and noncolinear calculation for it with VASP.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the *standard* VASP distribution cannot deal with external magnetic fields, but there are a number of papers in which VASP has been modified to enable calculations with an external magnetic field.

This [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.107202) by Bousquet, Spaldin, and Delaney explains how to incorporate a Zeeman field in the Hohenberg-Kohn energy functional (Eqs. 1 and 2 in the paper), implements it in VASP, and uses it to perform calculations under an applied external magnetic field.

Answer (score 4):

To address the paper, I don't believe they actually do any calculations in magnetic fields, they simply state what they expect would occur due to other calculations previously done by others.  Since VASP is a pretty closed off code, I would be surprised if anyone has implemented magnetic fields into VASP directly.

My understanding is that DFT tends breakdown in these sorts of calculations so you need a highly specialized code (BDFT?) in order to do these calculations.  This would likely require the ability to make psuedopotentials which are appropriate to the theory changes.  I am very uninformed on this part of the field though.

Staying on topic though, for those two reasons I suspect they speculate on these calculations rather than actually performing them.